# How to get the count from IQueryable

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, iqueryable

I am implementing paging in my GridView. From [this](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/153_Custom_Paging_for_GridView_using_LINQ.aspx) article, I need two methods:

```
public IQueryable BindEmployees(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    EmployeeInfoDataContext dbEmp = new EmployeeInfoDataContext();
    var query = from emp in dbEmp.Employees
                join dept in dbEmp.Departments
                    on emp.DeptID equals dept.DeptID
                select new
                {
                    EmpID = emp.EmpID,
                    EmpName = emp.EmpName,
                    Age = emp.Age,
                    Address = emp.Address,
                    DeptName = dept.DepartmentName
                };

    return query.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
}
```

And

```
public int GetEmployeeCount()
{
    // How can I not repeat the logic above to get the count?
}
```

How can I get the value of the second method `GetEmployeeCount` from the first method `BindEmployees` ? I mean without repeating the logic (the query)?

Comment: Can't you just convert the returned IQueryable to a list and take the count? <code> .ToList().count </code> should give you the count.

Comment: Upvote for you Ram Iyer. Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One option would be:

```
public IQueryable BindEmployees(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int count)
{
    EmployeeInfoDataContext dbEmp = new EmployeeInfoDataContext();
    var query = from emp in dbEmp.Employees
                join dept in dbEmp.Departments
                    on emp.DeptID equals dept.DeptID
                select new
                {
                    EmpID = emp.EmpID,
                    EmpName = emp.EmpName,
                    Age = emp.Age,
                    Address = emp.Address,
                    DeptName = dept.DepartmentName
                };

    count = query.Count();
    return query.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
}
```

The other option is to pass the query *into* the paging function.

Comment: "The other option is to pass the query into the paging function" - you may need to clarify this slightly.  The paging function would have to be a generic function for this to work, since Skip/Take also operate only on `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: ♦: Thanks. But I wonder why can't I get count from IQueryable !

Comment: @Jack - well, you could; but the Count extension method is defined for `IQueryable<T>` - not `IQueryable`

Comment: Hye Marc, Please tell me whats best in case of IQueryable<T> .Any() or .Count(). I get a IQueryable<T>, and both .Any() or .Count() takes time. I just have to check if it has any row. So I should use .Any(). Please tell which performs better.

Comment: @Deeps if in doubt, why don't you just *measure* which performs better?

Answer (score 2):

Make a function to use in both places:

```
//Can be private or public, your choice
private IQueryable<Employee> GetQuery()
{
    EmployeeInfoDataContext dbEmp = new EmployeeInfoDataContext();
    return from emp in dbEmp.Employees
                join dept in dbEmp.Departments
                    on emp.DeptID equals dept.DeptID
                select emp;
}
```

Then use it in both of your other functions:

```
public int GetEmployeeCount()
{
    return GetQuery().Count();
}

public IQueryable BindEmployees(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    var query = from e in GetQuery()
                select new { /*Do your anonymous type here*/ };
    return query.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but It's an anonymous type.

Comment: I'm suggesting to promote it to a true type, that makes it reusable.  Your can switch to using an anonymous type when calling this function if desired.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers: In this case, the datacontext has to be shared between the methods. Otherwise you will get a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

@Marc Gravell's answer solves the issue as stated, and is probably the best way to go. However, in the interest of providing options, you could also just repeat the `join` (since you don't need the anonymous type when counting):

```
private int GetEmployeeCount(EmployeeInfoDataContext dbEmp)
{
    var query = from emp in dbEmp.Employees
                join dept in dbEmp.Departments on emp.DeptID equals dept.DeptID
                select dept;

    return query.Count();
}
```

Comment: honestly, the "c" in Marc isn't a typo ;p

Comment: @Marc Gravell: D'oh! I've been following you forever and I knew that. Obviously I *just* woke up :-)